# Mark a Jenkins stage as failed in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I started out with the stage in the workflow like this:

```
try{
    stage('Example_1'){
        bat "${PYTHON} script_1.py"
    }
}
catch(e){
    build_ok = false
}

try{
    stage('Example_2'){
        if(build_ok){
           bat "${PYTHON} script_2.py"
        }
    }
}
catch(e){
    build_ok = false
}

stage('Cleanup'){
    bat "${PYTHON} script_1.py"
}
```

In case the script raises an exception, this stage will be marked as failed (red in GUI), but because of the `catch` the pipeline will continue executing. (This is needed because of later cleanup stage. Other steps won't run, because they are guarded with `if(build_ok)`). This works OK.

However now I need the exitcode from the Python script. This can be done with:

```
stage('Example_1'){
    exitcode = bat script: "${PYTHON} script_1.py", returnStatus: true
}
```

This is document to work in the following way:

> returnStatus: Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception. If this option is checked, the return value of the step will instead be the status code. You may then compare it to zero, for example.

I know how to mark the whole build as failed (`currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'`), but I need the stage to be failure as well.

So how to mark the stage as failed if the returned exitcode indicates it was a fail? (Not all non-zero exitcode means fail.)